# accessing method of the class inside of async module or

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I just noticed if I have a method in my class I cannot access it with `this` keyword in my other prototypes if I call them in async.auto or... please see the sample code for more clarification and my workaround.

Would you do the same? In other words is this the most elegant way in Node.JS?

```
function foo(config) {
  var self = Object.create(foo.prototype)
  self.db = nano.db.use(config.db.dbName);
  return self
}


foo.prototype.method1 = function () {
  // The workaround to use this.db is to store this.db in a variable, is this elegant?!? Would you do the same?
    var db = this.db;
    async.auto({
        check_DB: function (next) {
            // do some operations here
            next();
        },
        insert_DB: ['check_DB', function (callback, results) {
                // Note1: interestingly this.db is not going to work! in other words here this.db is undefined
                db.insert(value, function (err, body) {
                  //Do some other operations here
                })
            }]
    });
}

foo.prototype.method2 = function () {
  // The workaround to use this.db is to store this.db in a variable?!? Would you do the same?
    var db = this.db;
    db.get("baz", function (err, body) {
        // Do some operatiuons
        // Note2: interestingly this.db is not going to work here either!
        db.get("bar", function (err, response) {
            // do some other operations
        })
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly right. The  async.auto(... function is going to change the scope of "this". It's not particular to async, but to calling a javascript function within another one.

Same deal with db.get(... in method2. It also changes the scope of "this" in the exact same way.

So it is quite normal in javascript code before calling a function where you want to access "this" from the outer scope to assign "this" to some other variable just, just as you've done with:

```
   var db = this.db;
```

A lot of folks will assign this to something like: "self', "_this", "that", etc.

Comment: Thanks for confirming me! Is the second scenario expected as well?